# Code Migration from ClearCase to an Existing Git Repo

Tags: git, clearcase, rebase

I have a project on ClearCase which I have migrated to Git. Some commits were created on the Git repo and at the same time, some code changes were done on ClearCase.

My Git repo has v1.5 and ClearCase has v1.4 (production). We now want to migrate v1.4 to Git as a separate branch and also merge it on top of v1.5.

What are my best options for this? Should I create a separate repo for v1.4 and then cherry-pick from v1.5 or can `git rebase` help in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a branch in Git, from *before* the 1.5 version, and import your files.
If you have a ClearCase view (snapshot or dynamic) representing the 1.4 versions, you would go to your Git repo (set in the new branch) and:

```
git --work-tree=/path/to/ClearCase/view add .
```

That would automatically add/update/remove files in the Git repo compared to the ClearCase view content.

From there, a simple merge is enough to update the 1.5 branch.