# Can Git be used on OpenVMS?

Tags: git, clearcase, openvms

We are currently using ClearCase and ClearQuest for source control and issue tracking.

Our ClearCase client is running on a CentOS machine.
The OpenVMS machine mounts the required views via a combination of MVFS on the CentOS machine and NFS.
Then the code can be built and tested from OpenVMS.

Now we would like to migrate away from ClearCase and ClearQuest to something that has a bigger support community.

The question is whether Git could be a viable alternative?
And if yes, what would be the migration process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have [provided migration advice from ClearCase to Git before](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3A6309%20%5Bclearcase%5D%20git%20migration), but the [TLDR;](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26967852/6309) remains:

- Keep ClearCase in read-only for archive
- Take a snapshot of the latest code, and create a Git repository in it, modifiy its .gitignore (in order to not add *everything*), add a remote and push to a Git repository hosting server.

That is:

```
cd /path/to/snapshot/view
git init .
# edit .gitignore
git add .
git commit -m "import from ClearCase"
git remote add origin https://url/remote/empty/repo
git push -u origin master
```

(Note: I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53166310/6309) the Git repository does not have to be in the ClearCase view)

Comment: @Hein ClearCase is not very liked around here ;) But more seriously, this is more an open question, seeking recommendation, which is not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the initial question: it depends.

Have a look at https://vmssoftware.com/products/vgit/. It's not a full implementation, but it may do what you need. They say GPL, so you may even be able to add what you are missing.